# Memory Access in Nested Paging Environment

Tags: x86, virtualization

Consider the following instruction:

```
MOV RAX, (%RDI, %RBP)
```

In other words, store the contents of the `RAX` register to the memory location pointed to by the `RDI` register plus the `RBP` register. In a nested-paging environment, how many memory accesses could this result in, in the best case? Worst case? Show your math.

Comment: How about you show some effort? This isn't a "answer my homework for me" site.

Comment: Either your teacher needs to learn *actual* Intel or *actual* AT&T syntax, or you need to learn to copy + paste homework / test questions more accurately. Oh, also - don't do that at all.  *Sidenote: I am interested in what class this question is out of.*

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: *Modern Management Techniques: How to delegate work effectively*?

Comment: @KerrekSB How can you possibly know tha.... ahhhh, +1 :-)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if below answer is correct but will give you a start

For the given instruction, consider following memory operations:
 1. Fetch instruction from memory 
 2. Fetch value in memory location pointed by RDI register .
 3. Fetch value in memory location pointed by RBP register.
 4. Fetch memory location pointed by RAX register.
 5. Move contents on the memory location pointed by RAX register.

Assuming 4 levels of nested paging, below is the memory 
access calculations:

Best Case:
All memory locations fetched from TLB
Total memory accesses = 5, 1 for each operation.

Worst Case:
For each page with 4-level depth: 5 X 4 = 20 memory access. 
For all the 5 memory operations (in instruction): 20 X 5 = 100 memory access. 
Add 5 (5 operations) for Virtual Address to Physical address translations: Total memory accesses = 105

Comment: There's only 2 memory operations: the first is to fetch the instruction from memory, and the second is to store `rax` at address `rdi+rbp`. Second, x64 has 5 levels of nested paging (PML4->PDPT->PD->PT->page).